# How to left pad a column in Bash

Tags: scripting, text-formatting, whitespace

I have a bash script that prints the following results:

```
120,900
1160,001
80,730
600,165
6,310
1111,203
```

I would like to left pad that so the result will be:

```
 120,900
1160,001
  80,730
 600,165
   6,310
1111,203
```

I already use that line to keep just 3 numbers after the comma in the second column

```
awk '{ printf "\t" $1 "\t|\t" "%.3f\n", $2 }' MyFile.txt;
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text; just paste the text.

Comment: If you have that `awk` snippet in the script, you could probably add the right-alignment there, too, instead of doing it as a separate step in the shell.

Answer (score 4):

Use `printf` rather than `echo`:

```
$ cat 442817.sh
#!/bin/bash
numbers=(120,900 1160,001 80,730 600,165 6,310 1111,203)
for n in "${numbers[@]}"; do
  printf "%10s\n" "$n"
done
$ ./442817.sh
   120,900
  1160,001
    80,730
   600,165
     6,310
  1111,203
```

Comment: or replace complete `for` loop with `printf "%8s\n" "${numbers[@]}"`

Comment: Also viable; the main thrust was to demonstrate `printf`, as opposed to `echo`; I just wanted to "show my work" as it were.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk 'FNR == NR{ len = length; if (len > max_len) max_len = len; next }
     { printf "%" max_len "s\n", $0 }' file.txt file.txt
```

The output:

```
 120,900
1160,001
  80,730
 600,165
   6,310
1111,203
```

---

Or via GNU **`coreutils`**:

```
printf "%$(sort -nr file.txt | wc -L)s\n" $(cat file.txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ column -t -s, file | sed 's/^\([0-9]*\)\( *\)/\2\1,/'
   120,900
  1160,001
    80,730
   600,165
     6,310
  1111,203
```

The `column` output will be

```
120   900
1160  001
80    730
600   165
6     310
1111  203
```

and the `sed` command just moves the spaces between the two columns to the start of the line and inserts the comma in their place.

If the initial extra two spaces are not wanted, use

```
$ column -t -s, file | sed -e 's/^\([0-9]*\)\( *\)/\2\1,/' -e 's/^  //'
 120,900
1160,001
  80,730
 600,165
   6,310
1111,203
```